# Bootstrap 3 - media queries Tablet Breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, breakpoints, tablet

I have created a website using Bootstrap 3 and media queries.
This is my basic .css media query setup, using the mobile first approach.

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

In addition I have this meta set for Mobile viewport optimization in index.html:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

When rezizing my browsers chrome and firefox, all the breakpoints works as expected. 
For mobile, both portrait and landscape, the mobile version is showed. 
But while testing the web site on a Samsung Galaxy Tab and a Ipad, I only get the full scale site.

Could it be that I am using the wrong breakpoints for tablets? Or something else? I am confused.. due to the fact that it works on mobile and in the browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- EDIT 2 --

I did more digging on your full site.  I recreated your site locally and used a new version of bootstrap CSS, changing the break point to 767 px.  I then changed the breakpoints in your custom CSS to 767 px.  There was still an issue loading on iPads, the full site was still loading.

Upon further research I noticed the CSS sheet that you are referencing on a CDN for "Bootstrap Gallery".  The issue is with this file.  This file mentions includes the media queries for bootstrap!  After making the changed above and commenting out this file, the site loads in mobile form for iPads in Portrait.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Gallery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

-- EDIT 2 --

-- EDIT --

Twitter bootstrap was intended to show the full screen site for Tablets.  Note that small devices show the full menu while extra small devices show the mobile menu.

The break point set for small screens is at 768px - the width of the iPad in portrait mode - so the iPad renders as small screen.  TO have the iPad render as an extra small device in portrait mode (with the mobile menu), change the min-width to 767px for the small screen break point.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2155

-- END EDIT --

I'm curious if this happens in both the portrait and landscape modes for the tablets you are testing or ONLY in the landscape mode.

I would expect this to happen in Landscape mode with the standard Bootstrap settings as the width of an iPad is 1024x and the medium breakpoint for bootstrap is 992px.  Note that the iPad falls into that Medium category and Medium shows the the full menu and not the mobile menu.

If you want to change the breakpoints you can also do this by setting up a custom bootstrap instance.  Change the medium break point to somewhere around 1030px:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints.

The issue here is that people on smaller laptops will get your mobile menu if they don't have your website in full screen.

Comment: Actually it happens both in landscape AND portrait for the tablets I am testing... I was also expecting this just to happen for the Landscape tablet mode. I really don't get why it is not working for tablets at all. Could it be something wrong with the meta content then?

Comment: It will be difficult to tell without seeing your full code.  It could be an issue with the bootstrap classes that are used.  How does your site look in landscape mode on a mobile phone?

Comment: The site can be found [here](http://testurl321.site50.net/Stine_live/)
In landscape mode on a mobile phone, the media query applies correctly, and everything looks as expected.

Comment: I guess I don't test enough on tablets.  Bootstrap was designed with the intention of rendering the full site on iPads.  I will edit the Answer  with the full explanation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out for me, I tried to change the min-width from 768px to 767px, but unfortunately not with the desired outcome. I have been googling around, but have not found any solution yet

Comment: Did you only change the min width on your custom CSS?  Did you also try changing it on the custom Bootstrap install?

Comment: I figured it out!  Please see the update in the answer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I indeed had to change the bootstrap.css media queries as well as my style.css. What I found is that this change only applies for the Ipad.. I had to do some more [research](https://github.com/emilbjorklund/viewportmadness/blob/master/device-data.csv) for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 GT-P5110, I found that this GT has a viewport of 800px. I have little experience with responsive design in general, so I am not sure if I should set the media query to 767px, 800px or if I should create one for 767px and one for 800px. What do you think? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi Sepi.  I really think that it's a preference.  If you want to have your content render in full screen mode for most tablets in "desktop mode", than I would go with 800px.  A lot of newer sites I am seeing set there breakpoints for mobile as high as 959px!  Really trying to make sure that tablet users have the mobile experience. I think that with your design (tending to larger, block looking elements) it may be worth it for you to go higher, maybe even in that 900px range.  The site looks great.  I'm sure whatever you decide, your client will enjoy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and tips. I will consider setting the breakpoint to 900px. Hope you have a great day!